# How to fix a "Segmentation fault(core dumped)"?

Tags: c

I'm trying to execute this code, the compiling part is ok and the first half is ok too. I don't see where i'm trying to acess memory that's not assigned to the array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a[100], b[100], c[100], cont = 0, ind = 0, temp;

    printf("Insert a integer number\n");

    do{
        printf("X = ");
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        if(temp >= 0)
            a[cont] = temp;
        cont++;
    }
    while(cont < 100 && temp > 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
            if(a[i] == b[j])
                c[ind]++;
            else{
                b[ind] = a[i];
                c[ind] = 1;
                ind++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Exist %d different number in the list", ind);

    for(int i = 0; i <= ind; i++){
        printf("Number %d appears %d times", b[i], c[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What’s `if (a[i] == b[j])` supposed to do? You haven’t written to `b` yet.

Comment: Your second loop is capable of incrementing `ind` well beyond 100, and probably doesn't do anything like what you wanted it to do.

Comment: When I run it it prints out `Exist 300 different number in the list`, and then tries to iterate over the first 300 items of the `b` and `c` lists, which are each 100 items long... :)

Comment: Your `i <= ind;` should be `i < ind;` but `ind` is potenitally `100 * 100` and well outside the array you are writing to.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `ind` can grow much beyond `100` and thus `a[ind]` (and similar for `b`, `c`) can be an access out of bounds.

And when you write `a[i] == b[j]` in your code you are reading uninitialized memory because you never initialized `b` as Ry- mentions in the comments.